# Scala extracting values from arrays and nested arrays

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an array:  Array[(String, (Array[String], Int))] 
I need to extract:
 first element 
 last element; and 3rd and 4th elements elements of the inside array[Strings]

data from 3 records: I want to display only the bolded items

> > Array((**27120**,(Array(27120, 2011-12-01 09:59:17.0, 2013-09-07 08:29:37.0, **Dale**, **Hanson**, 2578 Ingram Road, Inglewood, CA,
> >     90309),**8**)),
> >           (**92694**,(Array(92694, 2013-01-25 04:11:10.0, 2013-12-04 02:31:35.0, **Stacy**, **Allbritton**, 4990 Clearview Drive,
> >     Sacramento, CA, 94215),**2**))
> >           (**40581**,(Array(40581, 2012-04-03 17:53:32.0, 2013-12-10 22:46:16.0, **Norman**, **Scanlon**, 312 Ocala Street, Sacramento, CA,
> >     95761),**2**))
> >          )

data should look like:

```
27120 8 Dale Hanson
92694 2 Stacy Allbritton
40581 2 Norman Scanlon
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having?

Comment: Simply store that array of tuples inside a variable for eg. val userData.
userData.foreach( entry => {
println(entry._1+" "+entry._2._2+" "+entry._2._1(3)+" "+entry._2._1(4))
})

Comment: Thanks!  This is great.  I now understand how to index into the tuples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data in in format, `Array[(Int, (Array[String], Int))]`, you will have to map over the array and extract the information you need.

your data structure looks like

```
Tuple(integer, Tuple(Array, integer)))
         |      |     |        |
         |      |     |        |
        _1     _2     |        |
                    _2._1    _2._2
```

example,

```
scala> val data = Array((27120,(Array("27120", "2011-12-01 09:59:17.0", "2013-09-07 08:29:37.0", "Dale, Hanson", "2578 Ingram Road, Inglewood, CA, 90309"),8)), 
(92694,(Array("92694", "2013-01-25 04:11:10.0", "2013-12-04 02:31:35.0", "Stacy, Allbritton", "4990 Clearview Drive, Sacramento, CA, 94215"),2)), 
(40581,(Array("40581", "2012-04-03 17:53:32.0", "2013-12-10 22:46:16.0", "Norman, Scanlon", "312 Ocala Street, Sacramento, CA, 95761"),2)))
data: Array[(Int, (Array[String], Int))] = Array((27120,(Array(27120, 2011-12-01 09:59:17.0, 2013-09-07 08:29:37.0, Dale, Hanson, 2578 Ingram Road, Inglewood, CA, 90309),8)), (92694,(Array(92694, 2013-01-25 04:11:10.0, 2013-12-04 02:31:35.0, Stacy, Allbritton, 4990 Clearview Drive, Sacramento, CA, 94215),2)), (40581,(Array(40581, 2012-04-03 17:53:32.0, 2013-12-10 22:46:16.0, Norman, Scanlon, 312 Ocala Street, Sacramento, CA, 95761),2)))

scala> data.map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2._2, tuple._2._1(3)))
res20: Array[(Int, Int, String)] = Array((27120,8,Dale, Hanson), (92694,2,Stacy, Allbritton), (40581,2,Norman, Scanlon))
```